# Worker nodes not joining the EKS cluster after upgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

We are have an eks cluster with version 1.16. I was try to upgrade it to the version 1.17. Since, our entire setup is deployed using terraform, I used the same for the upgrade by using `cluster_version = "1.17"`. The upgrade of EKS control plane worked fine. I also updated kube-proxy,CoreDns and Amazon VPC CNI. But, I am facing an issue with worker nodes.  I tried to create a new worker group, the newly created worker nodes got created successfully created in aws. I am also able to see them in the ec2 console. But, the nodes didn´t joined the cluster. I am not able to see newly created worker-nodes when i try the command `kubectl get nodes`. Can anyone please guide me regarding this issue. Is there any extra setup i need to perform to join the worker-nodes to the cluster.

Comment: Have you checked the logs of the nodes? Do they show a reason, why they could not connect to the EKS Control Plane?

Comment: @BastianKlein Thank you for the response. I also checked the logs of the ec2. The logs looks good. I see below line in the logs

[   29.382711] cloud-init[3695]: Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/kubelet.service to /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.
         Starting Kubernetes Kubelet...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Kubernetes Kubelet.

I don´t see any errror

Comment: make sure service account role for addon Amazon VPC CNI is bind to IAM role with managed policy `AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy`

Comment: Try steps from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73868433/worker-node-group-doesnt-join-the-eks-cluster/74278536#74278536